# Rails Associations Rspec

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, rspec, devicetoken

I'm struggling to understand the relationship that `owner = create(:user, device_token: device_token)` has to `owner: {device_token: device_token}`, I usually use `user_id` for this association.
2. What is the `device_token` method in the controller is doing.

```
describe 'POST /v1/events' do
   it 'saves the address, lat, lon, name, and started_at date' do
     date = Time.zone.now
     device_token = '123abcd456xyz'
     owner = create(:user, device_token: device_token)

     post '/v1/events', {
       address: '123 Example St.',
       ended_at: date,
       lat: 1.0,
       lon: 1.0,
       name: 'Fun Place!!',
       started_at: date,
       owner: {
         device_token: device_token
       }
      }.to_json, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }

      event = Event.last
        expect(response_json).to eq({ 'id' => event.id })
        expect(event.address).to eq '123 Example St.'
        expect(event.ended_at.to_i).to eq date.to_i
        expect(event.lat).to eq 1.0
        expect(event.lon).to eq 1.0
        expect(event.name).to eq 'Fun Place!!'
        expect(event.started_at.to_i).to eq date.to_i
        expect(event.owner).to eq owner
  end
```

end

Controller Code:

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)

  if @event.save
    render
  end
end


private

  def event_params
    {
      address: params[:address],
      ended_at: params[:ended_at],
      lat: params[:lat],
      lon: params[:lon],
      name: params[:name],
      started_at: params[:started_at],
      owner: user
    }
  end

  def user
    User.find_or_create_by(device_token: device_token)
  end

  def device_token
    params[:owner].try(:[], :device_token)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can identify uniquely identify a record in a database. Using the `id` field is the most common - but if you've got another way to uniquely identify a user, then you can use that, too. Normally, you don't show a user what their ID number is in the database. But, if you want to give them a way to uniquely identify themselves, you could create another field which is unique for each user - such as a `membership_number` or similar. It seems like in your case, `device_token` is a field that uniquely identifies a user.

So, your database cares about the `user_id` field - that's what it uses to tie an `Event` to a specific `User` (aka, the owner). If your users knew their id, then they could pass in that, rather than their `device_token`, and everything would be fine. But they don't know it.

So, they pass in their `devise_token`. You use that to fetch the user from the database, and then you know that user's id. Then, you can store that user's id in the `user_id` field of your `Event` model.

```
def user
  User.find_or_create_by(device_token: device_token)
end
```

This method is the one that gets a user based on a `devise_token`. And then this method:

```
def event_params
  {
    address: params[:address],
    ended_at: params[:ended_at],
    lat: params[:lat],
    lon: params[:lon],
    name: params[:name],
    started_at: params[:started_at],
    owner: user
  }
end
```

In particular, the line: `owner: user` calls that method above. From that point, Rails handles it under the hood and makes sure your user_id is set correctly.

UPDATE AFTER YOUR COMMENT:

`device_token` is being passed in as a parameter. It is also the name of a field in the User model. So, a single row in the user table might look like this:

id: 24, first_name: fred, last_name: flintstone, device_token: 123abc, address: bedrock, etc.

the method:

```
def user
  User.find_or_create_by(device_token: device_token)
end
```

is saying: go to the User's table in the database, try to find a User which has a `device_token` that has the value that was passed in as a parameter, and if we can't find one, then create one.

So in this line: `User.find_or_create_by(device_token: device_token)`, the first reference to `device_token` is the key of a hash, and it refers to the field called `device_token` in your User model.

The second reference to `device_token` is a call to this method:

```
def device_token
  params[:owner].try(:[], :device_token)
end
```

which fetches the `device_token` from the parameters passed in. This method basically says: Look in the params hash at the value inside the `owner` key. See if the `owner` key contains a `device_token`. If it does, return that `device_token`, and if it doesn't return `nil`. It does this using the `try` method, which you can read more about here: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Comment: Thanks sir,  and what is the `device token` method doing? To further clarify the API is for an iOS app so it uses the unique device token to determine that it's the right user and users device.Where is it being called in the controller? The syntax is a little unclear within the method as well.  What's clear is the params[owner] property is being passed into the `devise-token` method, but not sure what it is retuning.